# add class to one element of an array in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, class, styles

I would like to pass a style or a class to an element of an array when this element is on hover. My issue is: whenever I hover one element of this array, the class or the style is added to each element of one array whereas I want only to apply the style or class to the element on hover. Here I want the tag P to appear whenever his parent DIV is on hover.

Note: I did try to play with the id but I cannot find a way to add a class within the function. It seems in react that it is more common to handle this change within the render method. So, how can I do it without the spread of this style or class to each element of the array? Thank you very much.

```
 this.state = {
    meals: [
    {
    src: meal1,
    id: "meal1",
    alt: "Burger",
    name: "Name1",
    description: [
    "Thick slices of French",
    "bread stuffed with cream cheese",
    " fried in egg",
    "Accompanied by Maine maple syrup",
    "sausage links"
    ]
    },
        {
          src: meal2,
          id: "meal2",
          alt: "Sandtwitch",
          name: "Name2",
          description: [
            "Cheddar and Monterey Jack cheesesslices of French",
            "on grilled toast",
            " fried in egg",
            "Accompanied by Maine maple syrup",
            "sausage links",
            "warm tomato soup or Gazpacho"
          ]
        },
        {
          src: meal3,
          id: "meal3",
          alt: "Sandtwitch",
          name: "Name3",
          description: [
            "Cheddar and Monterey Jack cheesesslices of French",
            "on grilled toast",
            " fried in egg",
            "Accompanied by Maine maple syrup",
            "sausage links",
            "warm tomato soup or Gazpacho"
          ]
        } 
      ],
      onHover: false
    };
  }

  paragraphAppear = () => {
    this.setState({
      onHover: !this.state.onHover
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="gallery_section">
        <h1> Some pics of our plats</h1>
        <div className={"meal_container"}>
          {this.state.meals.map((element, index) => (
            <figure key={element.id} onMouseOver={this.paragraphAppear}>
              <img src={element.src} onClick={this.effectPictures} />
              <div
                id={element.id}
                style={
                  this.state.onHover
                    ? { display: "block" }
                    : { display: "none" }
                }
              >
                <p>{element.name}</p>
              </div>
            </figure>
          ))}
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to keep track of the ID of the hovered element as well. For that first change the `paragraphAppear` method to accept an element ID as below, and store that element ID also as a state variable.

```
paragraphAppear = (elementID) => {
    this.setState({
      onHover: !this.state.onHover,
      hoverID: elementID
    });
};
```

Then pass the element ID from the `onMouseOver` callback as below.

```
<figure key={element.id} onMouseOver={() => this.paragraphAppear(element.id)}>
```

Finally, check whether the hover is enabled as well as the element ID when applying the style.

```
<div
    id={element.id}
    style={
        (this.state.onHover && (this.state.hoverID === element.id))
            ? { display: "block" }
            : { display: "none" }
    }>
```

**See a working [code sandbox sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-star-q08i9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) here** (Check `Test.js`)

Comment: I have just done it, sorry I am new.   And I couldn't vote, as I didn't earn enough privilege otherwise I would have done it. :) see you.